# (zoom center) How to scroll a Netbeans RCP Scene to a given position?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, scene, autoscroll

Does anyone know how can I zoom in a `Scene` (containing multiple `Widgets`), keeping the center of the visible area (or any given point, eg. the mouse location) constant ?

Doing this kind of thing with Swing-only components is not quite difficult, but with the NB 7.4 Visual library, I don't success in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActionFactory` factory class provides several built-in actions.

For zoom it provides,

- createCenteredZoomAction(double zoomMultiplier)
- createMouseCenteredZoomAction(double zoomMultiplier)
- createZoomAction()
- createZoomAction(double zoomMultiplier, boolean animated)

Usage:
To your Scene add this:

```
getActions().addAction(ActionFactory.createMouseCenteredZoomAction(1.1));
```

[ActionFactory class docs.](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-visual/org/netbeans/api/visual/action/ActionFactory.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'd never care about `createCenteredZoomAction`.